# converting YUV to RGB change colour to green

Tags: camera

I need to save picture without losing any data. Using PNG is not an option as it takes more than 5 seconds to save and this is too slow for my project.

I used `campera.capture('image01.data','yuv')` as suggested by official documents to store data without compression.

Then I used the same document to read files and convert YUV format to RGB.
Document link: 
[Pi camera offical document](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#array-capture)

but this is what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data to be stored in RGB rather than YUV, you could try

```
camera.capture('image.data', 'rgb')
```

Comment: Using RGB doubles the size of files, so it takes again more than 5 seconds to capture and write data on SD card, specially with max resolution on camera V2. RGB files are about 22mb in this case.

Comment: You can use a RAM drive to eliminate the time it takes to save the image.